# How to modify org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.deployers.impl.FileConfigurationParser

Tags: activemq-artemis

In `org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.deployers.impl.FileConfigurationParser` there is one line code:

```java
config.setThreadPoolMaxSize(getInteger(e, "thread-pool-max-size", config.getThreadPoolMaxSize(), Validators.MINUS_ONE_OR_GT_ZERO));
```

How do I modify/patch this code?  Is it possible?

Until now, I only have patched `org.apache.activemq.artemis.ra.ActiveMQResourceAdapter.java`.

Comment: Why do you want to modify this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to modify this code. Simply grab the source from the [ActiveMQ Artemis GitHub repository](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis) and modify it as you need.

That said, it' unclear why you need to modify this code so it may not be a good solution to your problem.